# Basic difference between two tables

Tags: sql, postgresql

I am attempting a very basic difference function in postgresql.  Table 1 and Table 2 have identical columns.  Only difference is Table 1 has some surplus rows.  I would like to select for surplus rows only:

```
SELECT *
FROM   table1
WHERE  NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from table2);
```

The query above returns nothing when I know there are surplus rows.

Answer (score 4):

I think you are looking for `except`:

```
select t1.*
from table1 t1
except
select t2.*
from table2 t2;
```

Note that the two tables must have the same number of columns, and the columns must all be of the same type.  You can review the documentation [here](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/queries-union.html).

Comment: Thanks.  Are t1/t2 ways to select for specific columns?  If I want to look across all columns, do I just omit t1/t2?

Comment: @ZJAY No, `table1 t1` means aliasing `table1` as `t1`. The `.*` means across all columns.

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to use NOT EXISTS you're missing the joining of your table's keys in the inner where clause. Try:

```
SELECT *
FROM table1 t1
WHERE NOT EXISTS (SELECT * from table2 t2 WHERE t2.id = t1.id);
```